# How many strings can we form with the set $\{L, M, N\}$ with exactly $2$ occurrences of $N$ and $M$

Tags: combinatorics

How many strings can we form with the set $\{L, M, N\}$ with exactly $2$ occurrences of $N$ and $2$ occurrences of  $M$.   and $n$ occurrence of $L$.

I tried to do it manually for $n = 0, n = 1, ...$ and see a pattern

But the sets became way too big and it was hard to handle. Can I use a formula to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have to pick $4$ places for the $M$'s and $N$'s, so that's $n+4 \choose 4$ possibilities. Once  those $4$ places, you can pick the two places for the $M$'s in ${4 \choose 2 }=6$ ways

Total: $6 \cdot {n+4 \choose 4}$

Comment: n is the amount of L's, so plz fix it to ${n+4}\choose{4}$

Comment: @friedvir should it be ${n+4}\choose{4}$ . 6 ?
If so can you explain me the second part about 6 ways. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the second part is to choose which of those 4 places goes for the 2 occurrences of the letter M, which equals to 6 by the mathematical definition of choose operation

Comment: Thanks, I get it now

Comment: @friedvir Right!  I was thinking $n$ total, but you're absolutely right. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: @SimonFraser Thanks for fixing! :)